# Summing an Array of Numbers but Receiving Error when Run

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to sum an array of numbers.  The array has a length determined by an input and then the user gives the array.  There were no compilation errors and I am able to run other programs.  On the immediate start of running the program I am given a message that program has stopped working and that windows is searching for solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum, length, count;
    int array[length];
    sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&length);
    scanf("%d",&sum);
    for(count=0; count<length-1; count++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[count];
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  un indent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces per indent level (never use tabs) as that is wide enough to be visible, even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code does not enable the user to enter the values into `array[]` so the problem description does not match the posted code.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare your `array` it depends on `length` but you ask the user for `length` after.

A solution could be to ask the user for `length` (`scanf("%d",&length);`) before declaring your actual `array` (`int array[length];`).

Answer (score 0):

you should move `int array[length]` to after `scanf("%d", &length)`. But it is not allowed in C to declare variables after the first non-declaration (it is however possible if you compile this program as C++).

In fact, in standard C you can't have a non-const length definition for an array variable. gcc on the other hand for example allows this nevertheless.

In your case, the problem is that `length` has an undefined value at the declaration of `int array[length];`. If you are lucky, your data segment has been initialized to zero (there is no guarantee for that) but otherwise, it may be any value, including a value which leads the program to exceed your physical memory.

A more standard way of doing this is:

```
int *array = NULL;

scanf("%d",&length);

...
array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
...
free(array);
```

---

By the way, even after fixing that, you will most likely get random numbers because you never actually assign the contents of the elements of `array`.

Comment: variable declaration after first non-declaration is legal in C99.Furthermore variable length arrays are strictly supported only in C99 (optional in later versions). Which means that variable declaration after first non-declaration is perfectly valid thing for a program that uses VLAs.

Comment: Why do you cast the return of `malloc()`?  It is not recommended in C.  (although required in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Local variable are initialized to 0. Hence value of length is 0. So you array is of length. You are then reading length, say 10, from stdin and expect the array to be of length 10. This can't be. Since this is a stack variable, the size is determined in time of pre-processing and not in run time. If you want to define the array length in run time then use malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int sum, length, count;
    int *array;
    sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    scanf("%d",&sum);
    array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    if (array == NULL) return 0;
    memset(array, length, 0);
    for(count=0; count<length-1; count++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[count];
    }
    printf("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Local variables are *not* initialized to 0.

Comment: Variable initialization is implementation specific.  Compiler writers can handle this several ways without violating the C standards.  Using an uninitialized variable will therefore lead to undefined behavior in your code.  It may work one time, then not the next.

Comment: Very sorry for the mistake - NeilB

Answer (score 0):

first problem:

the `length` variable is being used to set the number of entries in the `array[]`, before the variable `length` is set. Therefore, `length` will contain what ever trash happens to be on the stack when the program starts so the number of entries defined in `array[]` is an unknown. 
This results in undefined behaviour and could lead to a seg fault event, depending on what was on the stack and what the user entered for `length`.

second problem:

The array array[] is never initialized so will contain what ever trash is on the stack at program startup.  This means the value being printed could be anything.  And the 'sum' could overflow, depending on the trash values in `array[]`

Comment: I have solved the first problem.  For the second problem I am having trouble.  I tried to set the array to zero with array = {0}, immediately after defining the array[length].  However, this gave a compiler error.

Comment: 1) in C, refering to an array name gets the address of the first byte of the array.  Not what you want.  2) to `initialize an array` to an initial value, use code similar to: `int array[length] = {0};`   Remember, initialization is performed when the variable is declared. (not some instructions later).  for assigning a value to each entry in an array, the best way is a loop, but your code could do the `initialization` with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

OP program lacks the part of data input, it's asking for `sum` instead of the values to sum, which is weird. The only inputs requested are also never checked (the return value of `scanf` must always be checked).

In C (at least C99 and optionally C11) Variable Length Arrays, like the one defined by `int array[length]`, can be used, but the variable `length` here is used uninitialized and before it is even asked to the user.

Moreover, the loop where the sum is calculated stops before the last element of the array (not really a big deal in this case, considering that all those variables are uninitialized...).

A better way to perform this task could be this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// helper function to read an integer from stdin
int read_int( int *value ) {
    int ret = 0;
    while ( (ret = scanf("%d", value)) != 1 ) {
        if ( ret == EOF ) {
            printf("Error: Unexpected end of input.\n");
            break;
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]");                        // ignore the rest of the line
        printf("Please, enter a number!\n");
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    int sum = 0,
        length = 0,
        count,
        i;

    printf("Please, enter the number of values you want to add: ");
    if ( read_int(&length) == EOF )
        return -1;

    // Use a VLA to store the numbers
    int array[length];

    // input the values
    for ( count = 0; count < length; ++count ) {
        // please, note    ^^^^^^^^   the range check
        printf("Value n° %2d: ", count + 1);
        if ( read_int(&array[count]) == EOF ) {
            printf("Warning: You entered only %d values out of %d.\n",
                    count, length);
            break;
        }
    // you can sum the values right here, without using an array...
    }

    // sum the values in the array
    for ( i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        //       ^^^^^^^^^ sum only the inputted values
        sum += array[i];
    }
    printf("The sum of the values is:\n%d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```